# Eloquent updateOrCreate not updating

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, slim

I am having trouble using updateOrCreate.

The below code is SUCCESSFULLY creating a new row; however when it comes to updating an existing row it doesn't work at all!

```
comm_helpful::updateOrCreate(
           ['ID' => 1],
           ['time' => 3000]
        );
```

This works exactly as expected:

```
comm_helpful::where('ID', 1)->update(['time' => 3000]);
```

I've stripped the examples above back to bare minimums (which I did as part of debugging) and it's still not working!!

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: are you getting a `MassAssignmentException` ?  and in your model have you defined the fields in `protected $fillable` variable for mass assignment?

Comment: show us your controller and your update form

Comment: No error/exception and I have set $fillable on the model

Comment: could there be anything listening for the `updating` event for that model? any missing fields in `fillable`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, after almost completely pulling my hair out; I found the problem where Eloquent is setting:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
```

which is used on the update method and returned by getKeyName().

```
protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query)
{

    $query->where($this->getKeyName(), '=', $this->getKeyForSaveQuery());

    return $query;
}
```

I then realised my 'id' on the tale was uppercase and not lower case!

I guess that means my answer is that I need to ensure I am using lowercase 'id' for the primary key or overriding it on the Model

```
protected $primaryKey = 'ID';
```

Answer (score 13):

I have a similar problem.
My model had:

```
protected $fillable = ['user_x_cliente_id','internet_cliente_id'];
```

The status has 0.

```
              $habilita = leilao_habs::updateOrCreate(
                  [
                    'user_x_cliente_id' => $user_x_cliente->id,
                    'internet_cliente_id' => $int_cli->id
                  ],
                  ['status' => 1]
               );

               dd($habilita);
```

After execute the updateOrCreate , the status still 0 and No get MassAssignmentException error.

The solution was change the model adding the status to protected $fillable:

```
protected $fillable = ['user_x_cliente_id','internet_cliente_id','status'];
```

Now the updateOrCreate works changing the status.

Comment: While it is typically the cause, the OP already stated that it wasn't a mass assignment error in the comments